# Get attribute of a clicked table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table as follows :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="background: white; margin-top: 5px;">
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th style="width: 5%">#</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Sub Group</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody id="allAccessInfo" name="allAccessRow">
       <tr class="test" access_id="1">
         <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i></th>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Custom Order</td>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Art Tab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="test" access_id="2">
         <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i></th>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Custom Order</td>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Credit Tab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="test" access_id="3">
         <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i></th>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Custom Order</td>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Imprint Tab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="test" access_id="4">
         <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i></th>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Custom Order</td>
         <td id="name_file_edit_undefined">Information Tab</td>
       </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the access_id of the row clicked. I tried to do it as follows but it is giving undefined :

```
    $('tbody[name="allAccessRow"]').click(function(event)
            {

                alert($(this).attr('access_id'));

            }
    );
```

How can I get it ? As , I get the table rows with ajax I cannot bind it with table row with as `$('tr.test').click(function(event)` because the row does not exists at first when javascript loads. So, I have bound the `<tbody id="allAccessInfo" name="allAccessRow">` for click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in the context of your code is not the `tr`, but the `tbody`.  And the `tbody` does not have an `access_id` attribute -- hence the "undefined".  You could change it as follows:

```
$('tbody[name="allAccessRow"]').on('click', 'tr.test', function(event)
    {
        alert($(this).attr('access_id'));
    }
);
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're using AJAX to append contents to the tbody. Please bind event click to tr after you append these rows to your code:

```
$('#allAccessInfo').find('tr')
    .unbind('click')
    .bind('click', function(event)
    {
       alert($(this).attr('access_id'));
    }
);
```

We are finding **tr (not tbody)**

Comment: The OP stated that he fetches the table rows using `ajax`.  Since they are dynamically created, he can't bind directly to the click event on the table row.  That's why he's binding to the `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** bind the click event, in the success handler as you fetch each row.

```
$.ajax(config).done(function(response){

    $('TR',response).each(function(i,tr){

         $(tr).bind('click', this.someCommonCallback );

         $('tbody').append( tr );
    });
});
```

where `someCommonCallback` returns the attribute you are seeking from the row.